# RRule problem on Weekly with time specified before 8AM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rrule

[image]

I wanted it to start at June 14 12AM(or before 8am), then every Wednesday and Friday, but it returns a day after(June 15, 17, ...), which is Thursday and Saturday.

Please help me solve the issue. Thanks!

I already reported it in github : https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule/issues/586 , i just put it here in case this might be noticed faster.